# Testing a location based iOS application using Frank

Tags: ios, testing, frank

I am investigating the available testing frameworks for iOS,
I want to write tests for an iOS app that are location dependent, like if you are at place A (I mean geo-location) this testStep should fail and that one should succeed and in location B the situation is the other way around,

Is there a way to simulate being at a location when writing Frank tests, in the simulator, and not by manually choosing a gpx file for each test separately,

EDIT: to make it clear, I want to do it in my tests, so it should be done in my code or with calling an external script or in some automatic way, I want to run tests that should happen in different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as of Frank 1.1.1 you can now ask Frank to simulate a location using the set_location method. For an example of how this works take a look at [this step definition](https://github.com/TestingWithFrank/Frank/blob/master/example/Controls/features/step_definitions/location_steps.rb) from the example app that comes with Frank.